# Is my thinking correct for proving these statements?

Tags: linear-algebra

- If $H$ is a one-dimensional subspace of an inner product space $V$, then there exists an orthonormal basis of $H$.

This is true b/c $v_0$ spans $H$ for some $v_0$ in space $V$. If we consider $B=\left \{ \frac{v_0}{||v_0||} \right \}$ is an orthonormal basis for H where $||v_0||=\sqrt{<v_o,v_0>}$.

- If $x$ and $y$ are nonzero orthogonal vectors in an inner product space, then $<2x-y,y>=0$

This is false b/c if $<x,y>=0$ then $<2x-y,y>=-||y||^2$ .

- If $U$ is a $2$x$2$ orthogonal matrix and $\left \{ v_1,v_2\right \}$ is an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^2$, then $\left \{ Uv_1,Uv_2\right \}$ is an orthonormal basis for $\mathbb{R}^2$.

This is true. Here I found out that $||v_1||=1=||v_2||$ and $<v_1,v_2>=0$. If we go further, $\left \{ Uv_1,Uv_2\right \}$ is an orthonormal set and that means it is a basis of $\mathbb{R^2}$.

Comment: Your reasoning for the first two points seems good, though I would encourage you to show the algebra for the second point. For the third, how do you know that $\{Ux_1, Ux_2\}$ is orthonormal?

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking is correct on the first two statements. As for the last one, you should explain what you mean by "if we go further".

Since orthogonal matrices preserve inner products, then $\left<v_i,v_j\right> = \left<Uv_i,Uv_j\right>$, and since the original basis is orthonormal, we have: $\left<v_1,v_1\right> = \left<v_2,v_2\right> = 1$, and $\left<v_1,v_2\right> = 0$, so:

- $\left<Uv_1,Uv_1\right> = \left<Uv_2,Uv_2\right> = 1$
- $\left<Uv_1,Uv_2\right> = 0$

Hence the transformed basis is indeed orthonormal.

Comment: To be clear, the basis $\left \{ Uv_1,Uv_2\right \}$ is orthonormal on $\mathbb{R^2}$, so it is true? Just my explanation could be revised and expanded upon.

Comment: Yes, it is orthonormal. I would indeed strongly suggest expanding your explanation, as I think the one provided on your post doesn't explicitly show anything about the $Uv_i$. Remember, you need to show that each of those vectors has norm 1, and that they're orthogonal.